# Nokia Developer Web40 apps with localstorage javascript

Tags: nokia

I'm developing for a Nokia Web40 App and for some reason I can't use localstorage with javascript is there a way to do this?

Can I set a cookie if I decided to not use localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

the answer directly from the FAQ would be "Local storage isn't supported in web apps, however you can use widget.preferences to store data in cloud."

Comment: here's the link: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Nokia_Asha_web_apps_-_FAQ

Comment: I was making a point for you to add it to your answer not as a comment, if your going to reference something it's always best to include where it's from.

Comment: Thanks, still learning, got coupld of posts deleted when I had external links in them, thus trying to be on the safe side..

Comment: The reason they will have most likely been delete was because it was probably just a link. When you add an external link you need to provide something more then just the link mainly the specific part in the article that the link goes out too.